# why does unique() returns the same value?

Tags: python, pandas, unique

Consider test dataframe which has a column named "quantile0.1_mrp".
why does unique() returns 2 identical values?

[image]

edit: (as @jezrael commented, it is because of precision)

[image]

Comment: I guess because precision, what is output if convert it to list?

Comment: We would need to know more about the actual data in that column.

Comment: Could you post sample data from the column?

Comment: @DYZ - [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html)

Comment: @jezrael that was exactly what you've guessed. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with precision of floats, pandas/numpy sometimes display truncated values.

You can check it converting to lists.

```
print (list(test['quantile0.1_mrp'].unique()))
```

Possible solution is round values:

```
print (test['quantile0.1_mrp'].round().unique())
```